# Descriptive purpose of 'absolut genommenen' when applied to line segments (translating a math paper)

Tags: adjective, past-participle, mathematics

The statement is

> Dann besteht zwischen den **absolut genommenen** Verbindungsstrecken dieser Punkte die Beziehung ...

and then an inequality is presented (this is from a math paper by Wilhelm Blaschke).

It's clear to me that this is describing a relation between the distances of pairs of points which lie on certain line segments.  I understand that *absolut genommenen* is the adverb *absolut* followed by the past participle *genommen* (modified by the dative plural ending), and that *absolut genommenen* is serving a descriptive purpose, but I can't figure out what it's trying to describe/express?  No meaning from the LEO dictionary for *nehmen* seems to make sense when applied to line segments.

Comment: This just means that *absolute values* are considered, i.e. the distances are not directed/signed.

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: Antwort draus machen! :)

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  That perfectly dovetails with the actual inequality that was given.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Are all points on one line?

Comment: No, they're not collinear.

Answer (score 3):

The past participle is functioning as an adjective. Thus, it modifies the following noun. The *connecting segments* (*Verbindungsstrecken*) are being *taken* (*genommen*) in a certain way namely *absolutely* (*absolut*), i.e. not considering direction or sign.

The phrase can be translated into English directly by saying

> Then the following relationship exists between the connecting segments of these points, **taken absolutely:** […]

(I’m not saying it be great style or anything; merely possible.)

Comment: This was my original guess for the translation, but it sounds weird in English, so I didn't trust myself.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass That’s often a thing about attempting literal translations. They sound weird in the destination language while being perfectly fine in the language of origin. Often, you can even guess the language of origin by the way a literal translation turned out. Idiomatically, my best guess is that English and German would use completely different words and sentence structures to convey exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

> Dann besteht zwischen den absolut genommenen Verbindungsstrecken dieser Punkte die Beziehung ...

means in english:

> So there is the relation ... between the lengths (literally: absolute values) of the connection-lines of this points.

The connection line between two points is a vector. A vector (embedded in a plane) has two coordinates, and even more coordinates when it is embedded in a space with higher dimensions. Taking the absolute value of a vector (by calculating the square root of the scalar product of the vector with itself) means to calculate its length.

In German you have:

> Betrag (eines Vektors) = Länge (des Vektors)

some vocabulary (when talking about vectors):

- Betrag = magnitude
- Länge = length
- Richtung = direction

Comment: Thank for the clarification.  For what it's worth, when I hear "amount", with reference to vectors, I think of nothing else but the magnitude.  Thus, "amount", with reference to vectors, is unambiguous in my mind.